# Adding Dagger to an existing project

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

I'm trying to add Dagger to an existing web application and am running into a design problem.

Currently our Handlers are created in a dispatcher with something like

```
registerHandler('/login', new LoginHandler(), HttpMethod.POST)
```

Inside the login handler we might call a function like

```
Services.loginService.login('username', 'password');
```

I want to be able to inject the loginService into the handler, but am having trouble figuring out the best approach. There is a really long list of handlers in the dispatcher, and injecting them all as instance variables seems like a large addition of code.

Is there a solution to this type of problem?

Comment: Are your handlers extended from base class that you can modify?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to configure it in the base class? Each handler may need access to different services though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about having different services to inject. I would propose next solution.

**ServicesProvider**:

```
@Module(injects = {LoginHandler.class, LogoutHandler.class})
public class ServicesProvider {
    @Provides @Singleton public LoginService getLoginService() {
        return new LoginService();
    }
}
```

**LoginHandler.java**:

```
public class LoginHandler extends Handler {
   @Inject LoginService loginService;
}
```

**HttpNetwork.java**

```
public class HttpNetwork extends Network {
    private ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ServicesProvider());

    public registerHandler(String path, Handler handler, String methodType) {
       getObjectGraph().inject(handler);
    }
}
```

There is one week point in this solution - you can't easily change `ServiceProvider` for test purpose (or any other kind of purpose). But if you inject it also (for example with another object graph or just through constructor) you can fix this situation.

Comment: The other weak point is that I have about 200 handlers. It doesn't seem efficient to me to have to list every handler I have/add to the injects list.

Comment: In this case you can have BaseHandler all services injected in **BaseHandler** and use required for specific **Handler**. Or crate another base class for specific service. Unfortunately I'm not sure if dagger works well template classes